# Can't seem to replicate this timetable

Tags: tables

I'm trying to replicate this table in latex.

[image: Correct Table]

But, I can't get it to be correctly typeset.

**This is the result:**

[image: Incorrect table]

All the months get jumbled and I can't seem to make them all the same size.

**And this is the code I have so far**:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,array,ragged2e,float,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \label{tab:501}%
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \def\arraystretch{1.3}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|@{}}
            \cmidrule(l){2-13}
            & \textbf{Jan}                                    & \textbf{Fev}                                   & \textbf{Mar}                                  & \textbf{Abr}                                 & \textbf{Mai}                       & \textbf{Jun}                      & \textbf{Jul}                      & \textbf{Ago}                           & \textbf{Set}                          & \textbf{Out}     & \textbf{Nov}     & \textbf{Dez}    \\ \midrule
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{2013}} & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Medicina Interna\\ HSM\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \midrule
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{2014}} & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Endocrinologia, Diabetes, Metabolismo e Nutrição\\ HSM\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \midrule
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{2015}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Laboratório de Endocrinologia\\ HSM\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Endocrinologia Pediátrica\\ HSM\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Endocrinologia, Diabetes, Metabolismo e Nutrição\\ HSM\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                 \\ \midrule
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{2016}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Endocrinologia, Diabetes, Metabolismo e Nutrição\\ HSM\end{tabular}}                                                                             & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Medicina Nuclear Oncologia Tiroideia\\ IPOLFG\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Imagiologia\\ HSM\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Endocrinologia da Reprodução HSM} \\ \midrule
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{2017}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Endocrinologia, Diabetes, Metabolismo e Nutrição HSM}                                                                                                                                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Endocrinologia Diabetes e Metabolismo EMC}        & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Endocrinologia, Diabetes, Metabolismo e NutriçãoHSM}                                                               \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have tried using other packages but the end result is usually like the one above. Is there any magical package to do this kind of stuff?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `\cmidrule` but `\cline`, don't use `\midrule` but `\hline`.

Comment: please convert your code snippet to comlete but small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, which we can copy and compile on ours computers. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: @Zarko I have changed the code so it compiles. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Skillmon I thought those were preferred with booktabs. What am I missing?

Comment: @mirandacelso You should only use `booktabs` for tables that don't have any vertical lines. (And usually tables shouldn't have vertical lines). Since this one requires them, however, the `booktabs` rules are inappropriate since they add some vertical space around them.

Comment: @AlanMunn ah, I get it. That's what was causing the gaps I had in the lines of my generated table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quite a big text width for making a decent table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\newlength{\monthwidth}
\newlength{\yearwidth}
\AtBeginDocument{% after fonts have been set
  \settowidth{\yearwidth}{\textbf{0000}}%
  \setlength{\monthwidth}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-\yearwidth-26\tabcolsep-14\arrayrulewidth)/12\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\multicell}[2]{% #1 = cols to span, #2 = contents
  \multicolumn{#1}{c|}{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr#1\monthwidth+\numexpr2*(#1-2)\relax\tabcolsep+\numexpr#1-1\relax\arrayrulewidth\relax}{%
      \centering\vspace*{3pt}\hspace{0pt}#2\par\vspace*{3pt}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{ |p{\yearwidth}| *{12}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\monthwidth}|} }
\cline{2-13}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
& \textbf{Jan} & \textbf{Fev} & \textbf{Mar} & \textbf{Abr} & \textbf{Mai} & \textbf{Jun}
& \textbf{Jul} & \textbf{Ago} & \textbf{Set} & \textbf{Out} & \textbf{Nov} & \textbf{Dez} \\
\hline
\textbf{2013} & \multicell{12}{Medicina Interna\\ HSM} \\
\hline
\textbf{2014} & \multicell{12}{Endocrinologia, Diabetes, Metabolismo e Nutrição \\ HSM} \\
\hline
\textbf{2015} & \multicell{2}{Laboratório de Endocrinologia \\ HSM}
                    & \multicell{2}{Endocrinologia Pediátrica \\ HSM}
                    & \multicell{8}{Endocrinologia, Diabetes, Metabolismo e Nutrição \\ HSM} \\
\hline
\textbf{2016} & \multicell{4}{Endocrinologia, Diabetes, Metabolismo e Nutrição \\ HSM}
                    & \multicell{3}{Medicina Nuclear Oncologia Tiroideia \\ IPOLFG}
                    & \multicell{2}{Imagiologia \\ HSM}
                    & \multicell{3}{Endocrinologia da Reprodução \\ HSM} \\
\hline
\textbf{2017} & \multicell{5}{Endocrinologia, Diabetes, Metabolismo e Nutrição \\ HSM}
                    & \multicell{2}{Endocrinologia Diabetes e Metabolismo \\ EMC}
                    & \multicell{5}{Endocrinologia, Diabetes, Metabolismo e Nutrição \\ HSM} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. I wouldn't know where to start.

I'll see if I can make sense of that "blackmagic" you did in the Preamble.

Comment: @mirandacelso Magicians don't explain their devious tricks. `;-)` I just measure how wide is a cell containing the year and then divide the remaining space for the twelve monts (keeping into account the 26 paddings and the 13 rules).

Comment: Nice approach -- I like the `\multicell` macro. But I'm getting an error (code looks right): `./table-odd.tex:34: Missing ) inserted for expression.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.34 ..., Diabetes, Metabolismo e Nutrição \\ HSM}
                                                   \\
? ` (MacTeX 2017, updated 6 ii 18)

Comment: @sgmoye Just updated to be sure; no error.

Comment: This is now a puzzle. If I delete all the accented characters (or substitute **un**accented characters), the file TeXs without issue. I did check to make sure that no file is being pulled in from my personal texmf directory. The log indicates everything is coming from `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/...`.  I did add a random ã and got this error: `./table-odd.tex:40: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ã\\H (U+103)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.` Any suggestions? Using pdfTeX for this.

Comment: @sgmoye Bad encoding of the file?

Comment: @egreg Spot on. I had to reinstall TeXShop and forgot to change the default encoding to UTF-8. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: The only problem I'm getting is that months get out of alignment when I put them in CAPS.

Draft mode shows some clipping too. :/

Comment: @mirandacelso I get no problem, with the wide setting I used; in a narrower column there can be issues. If you look closely, the original uses a condensed font.